# Odd behavior in python lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, client, aws-lambda

I'm going to start by showing you how I configured my connection to AWS

```
session = botocore.session.get_session()
config = botocore.config.Config(max_pool_connections=100)
client=session.create_client(s3, key_id, Accesskey, config) #psuedo
```

I'm getting a weird behavior where every time I upload the function (which processes 100's of files from S3 in parallel) I get a good run time and memory usage (numbers not important). After uploading the function and calling it once, if I attempt to call it again it starts to slow down and use a significantly higher amount of memory. (~50s longer and 300 mb more) I'm curious if this is somehow related to the fact that I don't disconnect the connection or something of that nature? It slows down more after each run but if I re-upload the function it seems to run without a problem at about the initial speeds.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? Where do you call the "lambda" function I can't see :)

Comment: I didn't think that the lambda function code was relevant but as I said essentially what I do is access a file get a ton of information and then "del" the variable that I saved locally. Each time I access the file I tally on some values to a main set of data. I do this for all files so that all the files can add the tallies to the main set of data.

Comment: Actually for memory leak everything is important. We need to see your program to see where the leak is happening. As you are mentioning in other comments you use threading! For example such info would be much welcome! How do you call the code from the example above? How did you structure your threading? I have a feeling that this has nothing to do with lambdas :)

Comment: `for fileName in S3Files:`  ;                                                                                  `       `t=threading.Thread(target=updateTable,args(fileName,counters,context,data))`
`threads.append(t)`     
`t.start()`

Comment: Note : just used semicolons to show that its a new line

Comment: Try to use t.join() in your code to see if the threads are really closing

Comment: I started to do that, I believe this issue is resolved it just seems that I have issues with S3 connections that are causing threads that should take 4 seconds worst case to run 80s which is a topic for another board :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like memory leak with the library you use or code. You can run it locally and analyse with a memory analyser why it is consuming more memory with time.

Comment: I'm figuring as much but I can't see why anything in my code would be causing a memory leak. Further wouldn't each lambda function be reset with each call?

Comment: It won't get reset on each call. Anything that is global will remain as global for further use, the term generally is called cold start. Any further calls will be sent to the same instance. Only the instance value will be changed. If you are creating a connection on each call, then it might be consuming memory to keep the connection information and never get removed.

Comment: To be sure "global" would be anything declared outside the handler correct?If that's the case I don't have any global variables... Everything is done inside the handler with the exception of a couple helper functions

Comment: That is correct. Just becoz everything is inside the handler does not mean, it is memory leak free. If you don't clear all the resources that is used, that will also have a leak. The code I see above has something related to pool of connections. If you want to limit to 1 and see whether the second call throws an error.

Comment: I would get an error after 1 call of the function. It takes a while to process a file and I get a "pool is full error" How would u recommend I clear the resources?

Comment: As I'm looking into it, I see that when I run everything normally (no threads) it runs with consistent timing. But when I use threads it seems that even though the run time is cut short, I get an increase in run time in the next run. My guess is that some threads stay open...

Comment: Clearly it seems a memory leak or performance leak in code. You need to check the documentation on how to work with global connection pool.